# anchor menu description under each menu in menu.html.twig

Tags: theming, navigation, 9

I am currently displaying the Menu "description" underneath each link using menu.html.twig. by doing this:

```
{% if item.original_link.getDescription %}
  <span class="navigation__link-description">{{ item.original_link.getDescription() }}</span>
{% endif %}
```

The issue is that it's not anchored with the URL due to it being outside `{{ link(item.title, item.url) }}`. Does anyone know what I need to do?

Here's a small snippet of where my description is:

```html
        {% if menu_attributes.link is empty %}
          {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
          {% if item.original_link.getDescription %}
            <span class="navigation__link-description">{{ item.original_link.getDescription() }}</span>
          {% endif %}
        {% else %}
          {{ link(item.title, item.url, menu_attributes.link) }}
        {% endif %}
        {% if item.below %}
          {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1) }}
        {% endif %}
      </li>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
{% if item.original_link.getDescription %} 
  <span class="navigation__link-description">
    {{ link(item.original_link.getDescription(), item.url, menu_attributes.link) }}
  </span>
{% endif %}
```

Try the above to create another link using your descriptipion as text. If we need link then link() function should be used.